# Divide the anchor string value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor which I inject in HTML in jqGrid formatter as below:

```
var number = rowObject.number;
var plateNumber = rowObject.plateNmber;
var markup = "<a href=%Href%;>%Text%</a>"
var replacements = {
    "%Text%": plateNumber ,
    "%Href%": "javascript:Search.openViewByPlateNumber(" + number + "," + plateNumber + ")"
};

markup = markup.replace(/%\w+%/g, function(all) {
    return replacements[all];
});
```

Here is my `OpenViewByPlateNumber` function:

```
var OpenViewByPlateNumber = function(number, plateNumber) {
    // Do something
};
```

In the UI there will be a number in the grid. When I click on the number the `openViewByPlateNumber` function will be called. Everything is working fine for me. The problem is the plate number is a string type. It is a number but it can be `1`, `2`, `3/4`, `340/2` etc.

It's working fine when number is simple like `1`, `5` or `9` but if number is `340/2`, then the method receives a value of `170.5`. It divides the number. So how I can pass it as string?

Comment: `The problem is the plate number is a string type. It is a number but it can be 1, 2, 3/4, 340/2 etc.` Which one is it after all?

Comment: @lount, i just found the solution from Rory answer. please check it. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the values to the function as a string wrap them in quotes:

```
"%Href%": 'javascript:Search.openViewByPlateNumber("' + number + '","' + plateNumber + '")'
```

Comment: Ohhhh @Rory thanks. It works, How i can miss that>. I should have been trying this. Thanks